# c3js cursor misaligned with chart point when setting tick count

Tags: javascript, c3.js

When I set my chart options like so

```
data: {
  columns: [
      [
          'predicted',
          num1,
          num2,
          ...
          ...
          num365
      ]
  ],
  type: 'spline'
},
point: {
  show: false
},
axis: {
  x: {
      type: 'normal',
      tick: {
          fit: true,
          culling: true
      }
  }
}
```

then as I move my cursor along the chart, it's position is correct, in this example the cursor is on point '0' and aligned with the vertical line

[image]

when I change the `tick count` option, however

```
data: {
  columns: [
      [
          'predicted',
          num1,
          num2,
          ...
          ...
          num365
      ]
  ],
  type: 'spline'
},
point: {
  show: false
},
axis: {
  x: {
      type: 'normal',
      tick: {
          fit: true,
          culling: true,
          count: 5
      }
  }
}
```

the alignment between cursor and vertical line on chart is off, in the image below the cursor is still on point '0'

[image]